# Update only particular fields with prepare statement in php

Tags: php

there are 6 columns in my database table. But, I only want to update 3 columns. I am trying this code.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET name=?, class=?, subject=? WHERE id=?");

        $name = $data['name'];
        $class = $data['class'];
        $subject = $data['subject'];

        // Binding the params to the stmt object
        $stmt->bind_param("user", $name, $class, $subject);

        // Execute the prepared statement
        $response = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return $response;
```

which is not working. Record is not updating. keeps showing empty page. No response is coming after execution.

Comment: where is the SQL?

Comment: `bind_param()` is wrong.  I'll find a duplicate.  The first param needs to be 4 characters but "user" isn't right; it is more likely to be "sssi". Assuming those types are correct, you will need `$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $data['name'], $data['class'], $data['subject'], $id);`  No need to redeclare the variables.  Next time you post a question, please include the generated errors.